# How to delay methods properly?

Tags: android, wait, thread-sleep

I'm trying to run 2 methods but not at the same time. However, I've tried both `wait` and `Thread.sleep()`, but it doesn't delay method 2 which is an `Intent`

```
 public void run() {
    checkInternetConnection();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Forside.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
private void checkInternetConnection() {

    if (br == null) {

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) extras
                        .getParcelable("networkInfo");

                NetworkInfo.State state = info.getState();
                Log.d("TEST Internet", info.toString() + " "
                        + state.toString());

               if(state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setMessage("Fejl, der er ingen internet forbindelse. Venligst forbind til et netværk")
                            .setNeutralButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            launchsettings();
                                        }

                                    }
                            ).show();
                }
            }
        };

        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver((BroadcastReceiver) br, intentFilter);
    }
}

private void launchsettings() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.bur);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Both methods start at the same time or the 2. method starts directly after the 1.

Comment: Do you really want a fix sleeping-time? That's definitely not the best way for synchronize code..

Comment: Take a break and have a look at this tomorror or the day after. Then as yourself: "Why did I think of delaying a method or two? What is really the probelm that causes the issue?" and then go from there. Delaying things is not an appropriate treatment for task concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like this one

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context)
{
    boolean result = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null)
    {
        result = info.isConnected();
        Log.i("My Project", "Connected NetworkType: " + info.getTypeName());
    }
    return result;
}
```

then in you activity do this

```
if(isInternetConnected()){
 //TODO
}else{
 //TODO
}
```

Comment: Then I run the `checkInternetConnection();` before this code?

Comment: what you want to do exactly check internet conection and then run the activity?

Comment: Yes exactly if there is a internet connection :)